# Why is DictWriter not Writing all rows in my Dictreader instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I'm new to coding and by default new to Python, so please excuse my ignorance...I'm working on it.

I am trying to write some code (Python 2.7) to take specific headers from multiple CSV files and export them as a single file.  Here is my code:

```
import csv, os

path = 'C:/Test/'

for fn in os.listdir(path):
    if ".csv" in fn:
        with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
            with open('C:/Test/fun/output.csv', 'wb') as fou:
                reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
                writer = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=",", quotechar="|", fieldnames=    ['sku', 'stock.qty', 'stock.is_in_stock'], extrasaction='ignore')
                headers = {} 
                for n in writer.fieldnames:
                    headers[n] = n
                writer.writerow(headers)
                for row in reader:
                    print row
                    writer.writerow(row)



    elif ".csv" not in fn:
        break
```

The print request for the reader instance seems to print all rows from multiple files.  I am testing on 3 files with known rows.  However, the DictWriter output file only has the rows from the last of the files read.  It just doesn't make sense to me how I can print row and writerow and get different results.  Obviously my DictWriter is incorrectly written but I do not see where.  Probably obvious to most but I am puzzled.

Comment: You are opening the file to `w`rite (which overwrites it if it exists), not to `a`ppend (which adds to the end of it).

Comment: Your method of writing headers is overly verbose; `writer.writeheaders()` would have taken care of that for you with one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening your target CSV file and clearing it *for each matching CSV file you read*. Opening the file in `'wb'` mode clears the file each time.

Moreover, you *break out of the loop* as soon as you find a filename that is not a CSV file; you probably didn't want to do that at all; remove the `else` branch there.

Open the file *just once*, and continue to use it while looping over the directory, instead:

```
with open('C:/Test/fun/output.csv', 'wb') as fou:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=",", quotechar="|", fieldnames=    ['sku', 'stock.qty', 'stock.is_in_stock'], extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()

    for fn in os.listdir(path):
        if ".csv" in fn:
            with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
                reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
                for row in reader:
                    print row
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

I used the [`DictWriter.writeheader()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) to write your fieldnames to the output file as an initial header.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!  Any logic that I was applying to the issue was too linear.  read first then write...opening the Write instance first(once) does exactly what I wanted.  Point taken about the writeheader...there is lots of misleading 'help' on the web.

Comment: @dbell: Stack Overflow is helping to remedy the misleading 'help' problem, one vote at a time! :-)